# Why Terence Tao didn't use inductive hypothesis, Analysis 1 by Tao

Tags: real-analysis, induction, natural-numbers

I am currently studying *Analysis 1 by Terence Tao* and in the proof of *proposition 2.2.8* I saw author didn't use inductive hypothesis to complete the induction.

> **Proposition 2.2.8**: If $a$ is a positive natural number, and $b$ is a natural number, then $a+b$ is positive.

**Proof**: We use induction on $b$. If $b=0$, then $a+b=a+0=a$, which is positive, so this proves the base case. Now suppose inductively that $a+b$ is positive. Then $a+(b++)=(a+b)++$, which cannot be zero by axiom 2.3, and is hence positive. This closes the induction. ∎

**Notice**:

> Axiom 2.3 states that zero is not the successor of any natural number.

> In the above proof $n++$ represents successor of $n$. In standard notations $S(n)$.

**My Question**: In the above proof Tao used axiom 2.3 to show that $(a+b)++$ can't be zero. But why he didn't used inductive hypothesis anywhere? I think it should be like this "Since $a+b$ is positive, by inductive hypothesis thus $(a+b)++$ also be positive that is successor of any positive natural number will be positive". Please correct me if i am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: If anyone is reading on, and couldn't remember this $++$ notation. It is Tao's choice for successor function, and also is used in some programming languages.

Comment: @Frog Okay. I am mentioning what does $++$ means here.

Comment: Is the inductive hypothesis not used so that you know that $a+b$ is positive, so that you can then make use of axiom 2.3?

Comment: You are right   Muhammad: the induction hypothesis was not useful. The "proof by induction" was however necessary, since we are not supposed to know yet that every nonzero natural number is a successor.

Comment: @Frog There is no use of knowing either $a+b$ is positive or not. Suppose if $a+b$ is not positive, then still successor of $a+b$ will be positive.

Comment: @AnneBauval So how this proof is done by induction?

Comment: @AnneBauval can you please explain how? Because last peano axiom is principle of mathematical induction. And induction uses inductive hypothesis to show the implication $P(k) \implies P(S(k))$ is true.

Comment: Yes, so you assume $P(0),P(1),\dots, P(b)$ is true where $P(b)$ says that $a+b$ is positive, and then you use Axiom 2.3 to deduce that $a+(b++)$ is positive, i.e. $P(b+1)$ is true, hence by induction the result follows. Alternative phrasing: you prove $P(0)$ is true, assume $P(b)$ is true for some $b$ (which it is for $b=0$) and deduce as he does that $P(b++)$ is true, using Axiom 2.3, and conclude by the principle of induction.

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't know the order the theory is set up, but if it is the case that the only notion we have of natural numbers is that they arise by successfully applying the successor function, then it may actually be strictly necessary that one phrases this as an induction, I'll check

Comment: Thanks for checking, I agree then @AnneBauval

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, if $Q$ is true , then $P \implies Q$ is true. So we didn't need inductive hypothesis. So why we are using induction?(why induction is necessary) . The last Peano axiom is also induction and it states "whenever $P(n)$ is true, $P(S(n))$ is also true. Then $P(n)$ is true for all n".

Comment: We are using induction (i.e. last Peano axiom) because this is the only tool available to reach our goal, but we do not use its full power. It says "If $P(0)$ is true, and if $P(S(n))$
 is true for every $n$ such that $P(n)$ is true, then $P(n)$ is true for all $n$". We only use the weaker statement  "If $P(0)$ is true, and if $P(S(n))$
 is true for every $n$, then $P(n)$ is true for all $n$".

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh i see. I think i understood the notion of using induction. My understanding: Since our all tools are not working but induction (last peano axiom) is the only tools that helps us to proof the desired statement. Induction is not used completely but we are still using it because this is the only tools by which we are making progress ". Is this correct understanding? Please feedback.

Comment: @Muhammad I agree.

Comment: @AnneBauval Unfortunately No, i don't know but i didn't get my answer. But fortunately i understood what you said.

Comment: Although the question was not a true duplicate, [the accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4606261) contained (among others) the same explanation as mine. So, I think the present post can be closed as a duplicate.